# Spring security switching to http after login. How can I keep it as https?

Tags: spring, https, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security. My redirects were switching https to http until I found this post. Spring MVC "redirect:" prefix always redirects to http -- how do I make it stay on https?. I also had to set the redirectHttp10Compatible property to false in my AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver.

The problem is that https still switches to http after login. Once I am logged in I can set my app back to https in the address bar and it will stick. Also, I am using IP authentication for most users in which case https stays thanks to the solution above.

I am trying to add redirectHtp10Compatible to login_security_check or something like that but am stuck. Here my `security-config.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config='true' access-denied-page="/login">
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/styles/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/scripts/**" filters="none" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/error/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajaxTimeOut" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/checkSystem" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/adminUser/**" access="ROLE_SSADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login login-page="/ajaxTimeOut" login-processing-url="/login_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ipPreAuthFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="ipAuthDetailsSource" class="com.mydomain.security.IPBasedPreAuthenticatedDetailsSource" />

<beans:bean id="ipPreAuthFilter" class="com.mydomain.security.IPPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="preAuthManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="ipAuthDetailsSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="preAuthProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthUserService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthUserService" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
            <salt-source user-property="salt" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.mydomain.security.UserServiceImpl" />
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.mydomain.security.PasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="256" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Are you using SSL termination? If so, you might consult this thread on the Spring Security Forums helps http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108494-Spring-security-s-HTTPS-issue-with-load-balance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
    ...
</http>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-requires-channel

Comment: Yes I tried this also and requires-channel="any". But not working as expected. Any other solution?

Comment: Not really.  If I understand the documentation correctly, putting this on all the intercept-url's should work.  I might be wrong though.

Comment: Have you read this FAQ: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session ?

Comment: And I suppose your application server is configured for https and does not accept any http.

Comment: thanks for your answer and comments. No our server is also accepting http request. Do you want to say that the problem is due to that?? In that case what can I do now?? thanks.

Comment: For your reference I am using tomcat to deploy my application.

Comment: Hi. If I am removing spring security and adding this p:redirectHttp10Compatible="false"  to InternalViewResolver it works fine but with spring security after redirection it goes from https to http... :(

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/Login"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                             default-target-url="https://127.0.0.1/abcWeb/"
                             always-use-default-target="true"
                             authentication-failure-url="https://127.0.0.1/abcWeb/loginfailed"
                                  />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="https://127.0.0.1/abcWeb/logout" />
```

I have added absolute path for login processing and for the rest I had added this p:redirectHttp10Compatible="false" to InternalViewResolver